# Cannot get required headers from some IPs and ports to parse song title using ShoutCast protocol

Tags: php, http, web, shoutcast

I'm trying to extract song title from live mp3 streams using SC protocol. The php script works fine with some IPs and ports, however with some IPs and ports I cannot get required headers from the response to determine the meta-block frequency, therefore I cannot find the location of the song title in the stream. Here's my code:

```
<?php
while(true)
{

    //close warning messages (re-open for debugging)
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

    //create and connect socket with the parameters entered by the user
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);

    echo "Establishing connection to the given adress...\n";

    $fp = fsockopen($argv[1], $argv[2], $errno, $errstr, 10);

    if($fp)
    {
        echo "Connection established.\n";

        $result = socket_connect($sock, $argv[1], $argv[2]);

        //prepare request
        $request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $request .= "Icy-MetaData: 1\r\n\r\n";

        //send request
        socket_write($sock,$request,strlen($request));

        //set sentinel boolean value's initial value
        $headers = true;

        //put the segment to be parsed into a string variable
        $l = socket_read($sock,2048);

        $meta = "";
        $streamurl = "";
        $checkContentType = false;

        //Parsing metadata frequency and streamurl from response's headers.
        foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $l) as $line)
        {
            if(!(strpos($line, "metaint:") === false))
            {
                $meta = $line;
            }
            if(!(strpos($line, "icy-url:") === false))
            {
                $streamurl = $line;
            }
            if(!strpos($line, "audio/mpeg") === false)
            {
                $checkContentType = true;
            }
        }
        echo $l;
        //Checking if the content of the stream is mpeg or not
        if($checkContentType)
        {
            $pos = strpos($meta, ":");

            $interval = intval(substr($meta,$pos+1));
            $pos = strpos($streamurl, ":");
            $streamurl = substr($streamurl, $pos+1);
            $flag = false;

            //initialize bytecount to 0
            $bytecount = 0;

            //Extracting song title using SC protocol
            while($headers)
            {

                $l = socket_read($sock,PHP_NORMAL_READ);
                $bytecount++;
                if($bytecount == $interval )
                {
                    $headers = false;
                    $flag = true;
                }
                if($flag)
                {
                    $len = ord($l);
                }
            }

            //Determining length variable
            $len = $len * 16;

            $string = socket_read($sock,$len);

            $pos2 = strpos($string, "'") + 1;
            $pos3 = strpos($string, ";",$pos2) -1;

            $songtitle = substr($string, $pos2, ($pos3-$pos2));

            //Formatting the log entry

            $finalstr = "[".date("c")."]"."[".$streamurl."]".$songtitle."\n";

            echo "logged".$finalstr;
            //finalize connection
            socket_close($sock);
            //Writing the requested info to a log file
            file_put_contents("log.txt", $finalstr,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            //waiting 5 minutes
            echo "Logging next entry in five minutes. \n";
            sleep(300);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Content of the stream is not suitable.\n";
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Unable to connect to the given ip and port.\n Exiting...\n";
        socket_close($sock);

        exit;
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Can you provide an example of one that works and one that doesn't?  Also, why are you checking the content type?  Not all streams are `audio/mpeg`.  And finally, you are searching for headers in a case-sensitive way... header names are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried to access shoutcast programatically but I've run streaming audio servers in the past. There are actually two different flavours of shoutcast server and I would guess your program is trying to talk to one and these broken servers are the other type.

From the post [READING SHOUTCAST METADATA FROM A STREAM](http://www.mikejablonski.org/2009/04/17/reading-shoutcast-metadata-from-a-stream/):

> Turns out that SHOUTcast and Icecast (two of the most popular server
>   applications for streaming radio) are supposed to be compatible, but
>   the response message from each server is slightly different.

Full details about the shoutcast protocol: [Shoutcast Metadata Protocol](http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think my parsing code works fine because I can parse song titles from some IPs. And I parse the header mentioned in the first link you gave manually. The problem is that I get something like this when I send a request to some servers:
`ICY 200 OK
icy-notice1:<BR>This stream requires <a href="http://www.winamp.com/">Winamp</a><BR>
icy-notice2:SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8<BR>`
Therefore, I can't get the meta-int header to find meta-block interval...

Comment: Winamp is a media player and those streams must be expecting some Winamp specific response. Download winamp & wireshark and then connect and see exactly what the communication looks like.